# How to reduce response size of Moodle's "cron" page

Tags: moodle

I'm to setting up web-based cron jobs through cron-jobs.org to my site with Moodle installation. When I do the cron job through command line way,    `/usr/bin/php path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php`, I don't have trouble with execution and results; but in cron-jobs status of my cron task appear like "Response too big".

What can I do?

Comment: The problem is that when you run through CLI or if you open the cron.php page in your browser, there is lots of detail that gets returned. However, cron-jobs.org will consider a site broken if it returns more than 1KB of data. You either need to use a different "web cron" service or you need to reduce the amount of data returned by Moodle's cron.php page.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use Google Apps scripts:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script

1 - Create a Google SpreadSheet
2 - Click Tools > Script Editor
3 - Copy and paste code below: (replace url)

```
function runCron() {
      var url = "http://yourmoodle.com.br/moodle/admin/cron.php";
      var options = {
        'method': 'get',
        //muteHttpExceptions: true,
      };
      var maxRows= 1440;
      
      try{
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText().substring(0,50000);
        Logger.log(response);
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e);
        var response = e;
      }
      
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      
      // This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
      sheet.insertRowAfter(1);
      sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
      sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(response);
      
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
       if(lastRow>maxRows){
         sheet.deleteRows(maxRows + 1, lastRow - maxRows)
         Logger.log(response);
       }
    }
```

4 - Save and edit your project's name
5 - Click Edit > Current project's trigger
6 - Add a new trigger
7 - Set event source to **Time-driven** and type of time based trigger to **Minutes timer**
8 - Save and sign in to grant permission for your project.

> If you have a choice, do not use the web based cron. It is likely to be removed in a future Moodle version.
> ...it is recommended to only run the cron from the command line or set a cron password for remote access.

Reference:
https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Cron#The_web_based_Moodle_cron_command
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to find another web cron provider which does not have the limitations cron-job.org does.

See this one: https://www.easycron.com/

It's still free but can handle larger amount of data being returned.